# Understanding Type keyword in haskell

Tags: haskell

From my understanding of type keyword, `type` keyword creates synonyms.

```
type String = [Char]
```

But how can I interpret something like this :

```
type Newtype = Bool
      Int
      String
```

Comment: Where did you find that second code fragment. That is not valid Haskell code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem theoretically speaking, it _is_ valid Haskell; what it does is, it defines the type `Newtype` as `(Bool Int) String`. Which is not well-kinded because `Bool` doesn't accept any type parameters. However, `type Newtype = Either Int String` would be legal. — Obviously you're right though: this looks like somebody completely messed up an example of the `newtype` keyword.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, it is valid Haskell in syntax and grammar. But the type system will error on the fact that `Bool` has type `*` and not `* -> * -> *`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one can read in [the documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type#Type_and_newtype):

> **2 Type and newtype**
>
> The other two ways one may introduce types to Haskell programs are via
>   the `type` and `newtype` statements. **`type` introduces a synonym**
>   for a type and uses the same data constructors. (..) When using a type
>   declaration, the type synonym and its base type are interchangeble
>   almost everywhere (There are some restrictions when dealing with
>   instance declarations).

So `type <name> = <type-expression>` simply renames a (usually more complex) type expression. As a result the second code fragment is **invalid**.

It is however possible that there are higher order types in the `<type-expression>` like:

```
type Alias = Either Int String
```

This is because the `Either` type is a higher order type: it has "meta-type" `* -> * -> *`. So here you thus "apply" `Int` and `String` to `Either`.

Note that an alias does not have any special semantics: for Haskell `Alias` is the same as `Either Int String` and vice versa: every method that is defined on `Alias` works with `Either Int String` as well.

If you however write `type NewType = Bool Int String`, then the type system will complain that:

```
• Expecting two fewer arguments to ‘Bool’
  Expected kind ‘* -> * -> k0’, but ‘Bool’ has kind ‘*’
• In the type ‘Bool Int String’
  In the type declaration for ‘NewType’
```

So it complains that `Bool` is a type that does *not* accept any (two) type parameters. Therefore it cannot construct such a type.